# Table with with array of inputs duplicating row previous row when adding new row

Tags: reactjs

I have a table full of text inputs.  All the inputs are stored in a React state array (`newUserPledges`).  If I have values in all the text inputs and add a new row, the new row is duplicating the previous row input values.  I can't see why it would be doing that.

Here is my component with all the irrelevant code dotted out.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
...

const initialNewPledgeState = {
    campaign: '',
    date: dateFormatted(new Date()),
    pledges: 0,
    howPaid: '',
    confirmation: '',
    sponsor: '',
    notes: ''
};

const buttonRef = React.createRef();

const AdminControlPanel = () => {
...
    const [addPledgeOptions, setAddPledgeOptions] = useState([]);
    const [selectedDeleteUser, setSelectedDeleteUser] = useState('');
    const [selectedEditUser, setSelectedEditUser] = useState('');
    const [selectedPledgeUser, setSelectedPledgeUser] = useState('');
    const [selectedAddPledgeUser, setSelectedAddPledgeUser] =
        useState('');
    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([]);
    const [usersWithPledges, setUsersWithPledges] = useState([]);
    const [usersWithPledgesCount, setUsersWithPledgesCount] =
        useState(0);
    const [userPledges, setUserPledges] = useState([]);
    const [newUserPledges, setNewUserPledges] = useState([
        initialNewPledgeState
    ]);

    const alert = useAlert();

    const setUpUsersArrays = () => {
        getUsers('user').then((r) => {
            setAllUsers(r.data.users);
            const firstAddPledgeOption = [
                { value: '', label: 'Select a user to add pledges for...' }
            ];
            const usersOptions = r.data?.users?.map((u) => {
                return {
                    value: u.email,
                    label: `${u.email} - ${u.last_name}, ${u.first_name}`
                };
            });
            if (usersOptions?.length) {
                setAddPledgeOptions(
                    firstAddPledgeOption.concat(usersOptions)
                );
            } else {
                setOptions([]);
                setEditOptions([]);
            }
        });
        getUsersWithPledges().then((r) => {
            const firstPledgeOption = [
                { value: '', label: 'Select a user to view pledges for...' }
            ];
            const usersOptions = r.data?.users?.map((u) => {
                return {
                    value: u.email,
                    label: `${u.email} - ${u.last_name}, ${u.first_name}`
                };
            });
            if (usersOptions) {
                setUsersWithPledgesCount(usersOptions.length);
                setUsersWithPledges(firstPledgeOption.concat(usersOptions));
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getDatabaseStats().then((r) => {
            setDbStats(r.data.stats);
        });
        setUpUsersArrays();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(selectedDeleteUser.value);
    }, [selectedDeleteUser]);

...

    const handlePledgeChange = (e, i) => {
        // console.log(e.target);
        const value = e.target.value;
        const pledge = newUserPledges[i];
        console.log({ pledge });
        pledge[e.target.name] = value;
        const tempPledges = [...newUserPledges];
        tempPledges[i][e.target.name] = value;
        // tempPledges.splice(i, 1, pledge);
        setNewUserPledges(tempPledges);
        // const value = e.target.value;
        // setInputState({
        //  ...inputState,
        //  [e.target.name]: value
        // });
    };

    const addNewPledgeRow = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const tempPledges = [...newUserPledges].concat(
            initialNewPledgeState
        );
        console.log({ tempPledges });
        setNewUserPledges(tempPledges);
    };

    const deletePledgeRow = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const tempPledges = [...newUserPledges];
        tempPledges.pop();
        setNewUserPledges(tempPledges);
    };

    const customStyles = {
        menuList: (base) => ({
            ...base,
            // kill the white space on first and last option
            padding: 0,
            minHeight: '300px'
        })
    };

    return (
        <div className={'container admin'}>
            <h2>Admin Control Panel</h2>
            ...
            <div
                className={
                    'col-12 col-md-9 mx-auto my-4 p-1 border border-secondary bg-light accordion'
                }
                id={'admin-accordion-add-pledges'}
            >
                <div className={'accordion-item'}>
                    <h2 className={'accordion-header'} id={'headingAddPledges'}>
                        <button
                            className={'accordion-button collapsed'}
                            type={'button'}
                            data-bs-toggle={'collapse'}
                            data-bs-target={'#collapseAddPledges'}
                            aria-expanded={'true'}
                            aria-controls={'collapseAddPledges'}
                        >
                            <h4 className={'text-center'}>Add Pledges For User</h4>
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div
                        id={'collapseAddPledges'}
                        className={'accordion-collapse collapse mt-1 px-2'}
                        aria-labelledby={'headingAddPledges'}
                        data-bs-parent={'#admin-accordion-add-pledges'}
                    >
                        {!!addPledgeOptions.length ? (
                            <Select
                                className={'mb-2'}
                                value={selectedAddPledgeUser}
                                onChange={(e) => setSelectedAddPledgeUser(e)}
                                options={addPledgeOptions}
                                styles={customStyles}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <h4 className={'text-center'}>
                                No users to add pledges for
                            </h4>
                        )}
                        {selectedAddPledgeUser?.value?.length > 0 && (
                            <form>
                                <div className={'my-2 user-pledges'}>
                                    <table className={'table table-bordered'}>
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th width={100}>Campaign</th>
                                                <th width={120}>Date</th>
                                                <th width={80}>Pledges</th>
                                                <th>How Paid</th>
                                                <th>Confirmation</th>
                                                <th>Sponsor</th>
                                                <th>Notes</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            {!!newUserPledges.length &&
                                            newUserPledges.map((p, i) => (
                                                <tr key={i}>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input
                                                            type={'text'}
                                                            className={'form-control'}
                                                            value={p.campaign}
                                                            name={'campaign'}
                                                            id={`campaign-${i}`}
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handlePledgeChange(e, i)
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input
                                                            type={'date'}
                                                            max={dateFormatted(new Date())}
                                                            className={'form-control'}
                                                            value={p.date}
                                                            name={'date'}
                                                            id={`date-${i}`}
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handlePledgeChange(e, i)
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input
                                                            type={'text'}
                                                            className={'form-control'}
                                                            value={p.pledges}
                                                            name={'pledges'}
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handlePledgeChange(e, i)
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input
                                                            type={'text'}
                                                            className={'form-control'}
                                                            value={p.howPaid}
                                                            name={'howPaid'}
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handlePledgeChange(e, i)
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input
                                                            type={'text'}
                                                            className={'form-control'}
                                                            value={p.confirmation}
                                                            name={'confirmation'}
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handlePledgeChange(e, i)
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input
                                                            type={'text'}
                                                            className={'form-control'}
                                                            value={p.sponsor}
                                                            name={'sponsor'}
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handlePledgeChange(e, i)
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input
                                                            type={'text'}
                                                            className={'form-control'}
                                                            value={p.notes}
                                                            name={'notes'}
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handlePledgeChange(e, i)
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            ))}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <div className={'d-flex justify-content-evenly'}>
                                        <button
                                            className={'btn btn-primary'}
                                            onClick={addNewPledgeRow}
                                            disabled={newUserPledges.length > 9}
                                        >
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusSquare} />
                                            Add New Row
                                        </button>
                                        <button
                                            className={'btn btn-primary'}
                                            onClick={deletePledgeRow}
                                            disabled={newUserPledges.length === 1}
                                        >
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinusSquare} />
                                            Delete Row
                                        </button>
                                        <button className={'btn btn-success'}>
                                            Submit Pledges
                                        </button>
                                        <button className={'btn btn-danger'}>
                                            Reset Table
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    </div>
    );
};

export default AdminControlPanel;
```

Here is an example of what is happening.  I fill in values in the first row, and then hit add row and it adds a second row with duplicated values.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked my question in the Reactiflux Discord and got an answer right away.  I was mutating my rows state in the `handlePledgeChange` function.

I have changed that function to this and it works great now.

```
const handlePledgeChange = (e, i) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const tempPledges = newUserPledges.map((item, idx) => {
            if (i === idx) return { ...item, [e.target.name]: value };
            return item;
        });

        setNewUserPledges(tempPledges);
    };
```